# Why does the .Shape attribute in python have [0] always within it's index. If possible please explain in layman terms

Tags: python, numpy

Would like to find out what the index of [0] means within the .shape[0] attribute within python. The attribute is usually used to identify row figures within data

Comment: `something[0]` always means first element of `something`. `shape` attribute is an array, and `.shape[0]` gets you the first value of it

Comment: If i started at .shape[5] does that mean starts counting at index value 5???

Comment: To start counting at 5, you’d need shape[0][5:]

Comment: shape is an array of which your wanted value is 0th element